# Getting "email" is required error for SSO requests configured in SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, unqork

Has anyone configured SAML SSO for active directory? I am getting "email" is required error when a user tries to login into Unqork platform. Does this error means that email is required in SAML token? What would be the next steps to fix this error?

Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

- Create a UPN suffix which is the same as your email domain
- Map the local part of every account to the email account

This will populate the `userPrincipalName` attribute with the enterprise principal which shall be the same as the `mail` attribute.

In theory this should work.